# Android studio ListView error

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use listview in my demo application but whenever I am executing my application it will display an error that "Unfortunately application has been stoped". Can you please tell me whats wrong with this code?

**Following is my code:-**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/AssignListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/calendarView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/calendarView1" >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/date_display"
            android:text="Calendar view date display"
            />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Event Name:"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Event Name"
            android:id="@+id/event_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Event Description:"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Event Description"
            android:id="@+id/event_description"/>


        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Event"
            android:id="@+id/add_event_button"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:id="@+id/cancel_event_button"/>

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: would be helpful if u can post the exact error log

Comment: You must check the Logcat first to know exactly, which line is creating the problem!

Comment: listview can not have multiple child you can either use scroll view or use adapter to populate you listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View,
>   LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

**You cannot add Child Views to the [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)** So change Your Code As Suggested by @IntelliJ Amiya and @Bhupat Bheda

For More Details Check this [Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm) for List View in Android

Answer (score 4):

**Problem**

You must end your **Listview**

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/AssignListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/calendarView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/calendarView1" />
```

**FYI**

> ListView is a view group that displays a list of scrollable items.Listview can't hold multiple child in Main XML

Answer (score 4):

You cannot put any views (TextView,Editext etc.) inside listview control

Your list view tag look like below

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/AssignListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/calendarView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/calendarView1" />
```

or

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/AssignListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/calendarView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/calendarView1" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: For that, You should use ListView With Custom Adapter

Comment: you should follow this link http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply friends and after some try I got a solution.
**Following is the working code:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:text="Calendar view"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

    <CalendarView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />




    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/date_display"
        android:text="Calendar view date display"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>


    <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Event Name:"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Event Name"
        android:id="@+id/event_name"/>

    <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Event Description:"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Event Description"
        android:id="@+id/event_description"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Event"
        android:id="@+id/add_event_button"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:id="@+id/cancel_event_button"/>



</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```